# GA enhanced ecommerce session gets lost after redirect

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I am tracking checkout process with GTM custom events. All steps gets tracked correctly but checkout flow is broken:

[image]

- First `checkout` event with `'actionField': {'step': 1}` is triggered on entering checkout page.
- Second `checkout` step is triggered after filling form.
- Third `checkout` step is triggered before redirecting user to payment provider.
- After successful payment user is redirected back to my site where `purchase` event is triggered (4th column).

Most of payments (17 of 25) was successful but GA shows that 100% abandoned checkout process.

How can I fix that?

The second issue is that in ecommerce referrals I see payment provider in first place. I am pretty sure that this is wrong and it's caused by redirecting users after payment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set your payment gateway domain (i.e. paypal.com) in Referral Exclusion list, in Property settings.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!